# Stata foreach and forvalue loop

Tags: for-loop, stata

Here is my question:
Repeat the regression in part  1,000 times, drawing new values for the y, X1, X2 and u variables each time as specified. Compute the means of the estimated coefficients and also their correlations.
I wrote my code with for loop, but it just told me there is nothing changes.

```
foreach n in 1000{

  forvalues m = 1/1000 {

        local bb0 = 0
        local bb1 = 0
        local bb2 = 0
        gen u = rnormal(0, 5) if _n <= `n'
        gen x1i = rnormal(0, 1) if _n <= `n'
        gen x2i = exp(x1i) if _n <= `n'
        gen Yi = 2 + 4 * x1i - 6 * x2i + u if _n <= `n'
        regress Yi x1i x2i

        replace bb0 = b[_cons]) if _n <= `n'
        replace bb1 = b[x1i] if _n <= `n'
        replace bb2 = b[x2i] if _n <= `n'

}
}
gen b0 = mean(bb0)
gen b1 = mean(bb1)
gen b2 = mean(bb2)
```

Comment: What is the precise question here? The request appears to be to rewrite the code, but the problem statement is fuzzy. `there is nothing changes` can't be a Stata error message.

Answer (score 3):

Your report is most mysterious. On the face of it, this code never got past the first of several bugs. Here any bug mentioned would be fatal, but I report other bugs nevertheless.

The intent of the loop is evidently to hold the result of 1000 regressions, but each time round the loop the estimated coefficients of the last regression would (other bugs somehow not biting) overwrite any previous estimates in variables `bb0 bb1 bb2`. That in itself is not a syntax error, but even in outline the program won't do what was intended.

The outer loop is a loop using a single argument, which just sets the last observation used to 1000. In itself it won't produce any iterations.

Initialising `local` macros `bb0` `bb1` `bb2` is harmless, but quite incorrect if the idea is that that has anything to do with initialising variables `bb0`, `bb1`, `bb2`.

**Bug** Second time round the loop, the first `generate` statement will fail because the variable `u` already exists.

**Bug** The same kind of problem would beset the next three `generate` statements.

**Bug** First time round the loop, the `replace` statement for `bb0` will fail, as no such variable exists (see above: the local macro assignments earlier are irrelevant).

**Bug** The same `replace` statement contains a stray parenthesis.

**Bug** The same kind of problem would beset the next two `replace` statements first time round the loop, as no such variables exist.

**Bug** After `regress` coefficients are held in `_b`, not `b`.

**Bug** There is no function `mean()` that would work in the expression to a `generate` statement.

The code below at least works. The problem statement as reported is unclear on various details: for example, the sample size and the number of simulations could be different. As the tone of the question suggests an assignment in some course, at least the code for correlations is left as an exercise.

```
clear 
set seed 42 
set obs 1000 

quietly foreach v in Yi x1i x2i bb0 bb1 bb2 { 
    gen `v' = . 
}

quietly forval m = 1/1000 {
    replace x1i = rnormal(0, 1) 
    replace x2i = exp(x1i) 
    replace Yi = 2 + 4 * x1i - 6 * x2i + rnormal(0, 5) 
    regress Yi x1i x2i
    replace bb0 = _b[_cons] in `m'
    replace bb1 = _b[x1i] in `m'
    replace bb2 = _b[x2i] in `m' 
}

su bb0 bb1 bb2
```